# Gradle distributionUrl inside Jenkins pipeline

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to configure my Jenkins pipeline. I have to use the scripted pipeline and I'm not able to install any plugins. My problem is that I want to use gradle from artifactory on my server, is it possible to configure it somehow inside my pipeline? This is my code:

```
node {
  checkout scm

  stage('Deploy') {
    sh './gradlew uploadDebugToHockeyApp'
  }
}
```

I don't want to change anything in my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file because I want to use regular endpoint (`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`).

Comment: What is the gradle binary in artifactory? is it equivalent to what is at https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip ?

Comment: yes, it points to the same file but stored locally